# ClickOnce updates all files. Why?

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I've got small wpf application deployed using ClickOnce technology. The problem is that when I build new version clients download all files, though many of these files have not been changed. I use following configuration to make deployment manifest

```
<GenerateDeploymentManifest AssemblyName="MyApp.exe.application"
  AssemblyVersion="1.0.0.0"
  DeploymentUrl="\\...\MyApp.exe.application"
  Product="Egs.Client"
  TargetCulture="ru-RU"
  Description="My application"
  Publisher="MyCompany"
  Install="true"
  UpdateInterval="1"
  UpdateUnit="Weeks"
  UpdateEnabled="true"
  UpdateMode="Background"
  OutputManifest="$(ApplicationFile)"
  MapFileExtensions="true"
  EntryPoint="@(DeploymentManifestEntryPoint)" />
```

Even If I just change "1.0.0.0" to "1.0.0.1" clients will download whole application again.
Am I missing something or it's standart behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an assembly changes at all it will be downloaded.  Rebuilding an assembly counts as a change.  I typically skip Visual Studio for creating deployments and use [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx) instead.  Then I *don't* point Mage at the bin where all the assemblies get built, I point it at a separate folder where I manually copy in assemblies I want deployed.  Make sense?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I do not use VisualStudio either, I also use Mage for deployment. Am I right that if I use command like 
mage.exe -New ....
then all files will be re-downloaded and 
mage.exe -Update 
should be used instead ?

Comment: -New or -Update should not matter.  The main thing to watch is if you don't want an assembly to be deployed, you need to build your new deployment with **that exact same** assembly, not a rebuilt version of that assembly.

ClickOnce hashes your files, that's how it knows what to download; it compares the client's file hashes with the server, any files that are different get downloaded.  Doing **anything** to an assembly, including rebuilding it, will cause a different hash to be generated which will cause it to be downloaded.